# Question about hosting behind router

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I feel like a noob because I can't figure this one out. I have a linux machine (a raspberry pi running raspbian) behind a router, and I'm trying to host a website on it (port forwarding is not an option because of ISP).

To solve this, I want to route the traffic through a machine with a public ip, but the live of me, I can't figure out how to do the proper ssh tunnel.

When I run `curl 192.168.1.135:88` from within the network, I get " Welcome to my website". However, when I run on the raspberry:

- `sudo ssh -R 8080:127.0.0.1:88 -N user@my.domain`
- `curl marhuenda.in:8080`

I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to my.domain port 8080: Connection refused`.

But the port 8080 is open, I checked firewall the configuration. So I don't know why it isn't tunneling my request to the rpi.

EDIT:
Output of machine on my.domain:

```
netstat -an | grep 8080

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080                :::*                    LISTEN
```

EDIT: For clarification, I can connect to the raspberry on port 88 from any machine in the local network. (So `curl 127.0.0.1:88` returns the same thing as `192.168.1.135:88`).
However, `curl my.domain` rejects connection besides the fact that the remote machine on my.domain is listening on port 8080.

Other things that I tried (as per suggestion of others):
Use bind address: 0.0.0.0:8080:127.0.0.1:88 and change config to allow Gateway ports.

Still nothing.

Comment: Please run "netstat -an | grep 8080" on the _my.domain_ host and [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: At the moment the question is very confusing, let's see if we can clear things up. It appears that your pi has an address of 192.168.1.135 and you can connect from the internal network to port 88. The web server may be listening on a particular address rather then every address. Can you run `curl 127.0.0.1:88` *on the pi*?  If not can you change `sudo ssh -R 8080:127.0.0.1:88 -N user@my.domain` to `sudo ssh -R 8080:192.168.1.135:88 -N user@my.domain`? The next thing to try is `sudo ssh -R :8080:192.168.1.135:88 -N user@my.domain` an extra : before the 8080.

Comment: Debug this in steps: Instead of `ssh -R`, run something on your server that listens on 8080 (e.g. netcat), and then try your `curl` (or another netcat). If you still get "Connection confused", it's an issue on your server/server provider. If you can connect, it's an issue with `ssh`. Depending on the outcome, split what remains into smaller part, and test them again in isolation, until you find the cause.

Comment: @dirkt Thats a good idea. It seems the machine is accepting connections: ```nc -l 8085 ``` results in ```GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: marhuenda.in:8085
User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
Accept: */*
``` after I run curl on some other machine. So the problem must be in the raspberry.

Comment: @dirkt Okay, that was a very good idea. I was able to solve it in the end. (It was the bind address + firewall on the raspberry was not configured properly).

Comment: You can also answer your own question (and accept it after a cooldown period) in case somebody else runs into the same problem.